# Improper integral $\frac{1}{x^2(1+x)}$

Tags: real-analysis

$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2(x+1) }dx$ converges.

What if I write the same integral as
$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{x}dx +\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x+1}dx +\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2}dx$.

And we know $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges hence above integral diverges.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Please use mathjax in your question

Comment: Note: the first (main) integral doesn't  converge in $0$

Comment: Unless, I am missing something $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^2(x+1) }dx=-\infty$, and therefore is not convergent. Also, though you did not state so explicitly, the integral is being broken into parts by partial decomposition. Wolfram Seems to Agree: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=from+0+to+inf+of+integral+of+1%2F(x%5E2(x%2B1)

Answer (score 2):

It is not, in general, the case that $\int (f+g) = \int f + \int g$. The usual proof of this result is valid only when two of the integrals involved (hence all of them) converge. A simple corollary of this gives that $\int (f+g+h) = \int f + \int g + \int h$ when three (hence all four) of those integrals converge. In your case, however, as you note, not all of your integrals converge, hence this result is not applicable.